# if ... AND ... AND (...) OR (..)

Tags: php, if-statement

I need to implement this in PHP:

```
if submit isset
 AND myname isset
 AND adress not empty 
 AND phonenumber not empty
 AND email not empty
 AND ( 
 institution OR g_year not empty (one should be 'full') 
   OR
 donation_p OR loan_p isset (should be set)
   OR
 donation_m OR loan_m isset (should be set)..
)
```

What i've wrote:

```
if ((isset($_POST['submit'])) 
     && ($_POST['myname'] != '') 
     && ($_POST['adress'] != '')   
     && ($_POST['phonenumber'] != '') 
     && ($_POST['email'] != '') 
     && (($_POST['institution'] != '') || ($_POST['g_year'] != ''))
         || ((isset($_POST['donation_p'])) && (isset($_POST['loan_p'])))
         || ((isset($_POST['donation_m'])) && (isset($_POST['loan_m']))))
```

What is wrong with my code?

I hope someone will give me answer.. i hope you understood what i want ;D

Comment: Any parsing errors or other output upon execution?

Comment: I don't know. What _is_ the problem (aside from egregious lack of line breaks)? [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader or Crystal Ball.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/133242)

Comment: If you get rid of the overdose of parentheses, you will probably see the solution already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need "myname" set, but you are testing if myname != ''.
2. You need "donation OR loan", but you are testing "donation AND loan".
3. You should consider testing !empty($var) instead of $var != ''.

Comment: I also would use `!empty( $var )`, but be aware, that sometimes integers can be zero/0 – which is an empty value too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `if` `elseif` `else` instead of what you are doing now, that should work!